# How to update rule tile (brush) from Unity's 2D grid tile map palette?

Tags: unity

I have created a Palette in Unity and created a map using that rule
[image: draw map]

Now, I want to replace the current rule with another one, without having to draw everything once more. I tried to drag and drop the new rule on the same position in the palette, but the drawn map was not updated.

[image]

I am a little anxious about creating a (large) map unless I know of a way to update a brush without having to redraw everything.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a solution that I am using for the time being. I can add the new rule to the palette, and use the "fill" tool to change all of the tiles I want to replace. It is not optimal, but it was the best I could do. Since a rule (brush) will be used in large clusters, I figured this method could get the job done in a somewhat timely manner. I am still looking for better alternatives

[image]